# Not able to add JPA dependency into spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to add JPA Maven dependency to already created spring-boot project but I am getting following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.kame.demo.DemoApplication
```

When I remove it the error is gone.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:navin
```

I tried to find answer online but none was solution for me.

Also tried to create > Spring starter project > an there immediately add JPA, Web and H2 but still same error.

I am using STS IDE, is something related to it maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Is itself a demo project with an extending SpringBoot class as the `main` class of your project. But this dependency does the same :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

So there is high chances that both will clash...
The solution is to import the correct dependency for jpa and not the spring boot starter jpa dependency.

## EDIT

This one might do the trick instead :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

But I recommend you read the official documents to get started properly : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.RC2/reference/html/

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while I tried to add **JPA dependency manually** in POM.xml after creating Spring boot with Web only.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Root cause of the problem**:- JPA dependency jar was missing. verify:-
File->Project structure->Modules->Dependencies and you will not find any jar **org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**:2.4.3 (I am using spring boot 2.4.3 but in your case version can be different)

**Solution**:-
**Step 1**
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... and choosing the Invalidate and Restart option fixed the issue. can be a stale cache issue

**Step 2**
Under IntelliJ Idea open **POM.xml right click**-> **Maven**-> **Reload project**.
Maven will download the JPA dependency jar and will add into the project. Verify if JPA jar is added or not.

**Step 3**
Selecting File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... and choosing the Invalidate and Restart option fixed the issue.

NB:- If you are not using ItellIj id then please *force Maven to download dependency* (for step2)